# Image resizes with window, but black bar is displayed on some sizes?

Tags: html, css, image

I have written some code to make an image resize with window size of the web browser it is displayed in  :

```
<p>
  <a href="www.link.com">
    <img src="/images/image.png" style="max-height: 235px; 
                                        max-width: 100%;
                                        height: auto;
                                        width: auto; /* ie8 */" />
  </a>
</p>
```

It displays like so in some resolutions, with a black bar to the right:

[image]

How can I remove this black bar? What causes this issue? I cannot target it in Web Developer tools, it isn't present in all window sizes and it is not part of the image.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `max-width` values?

Comment: @JoseMagana Thanks, removed. The issue persists :)

Comment: Can you create a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) for this

Comment: I think thats a browser thing. letting the browser resize an image sometimes does that. e.g. setting dimension to 150x150 from a 1000x1000 sized image. I'm just guessing though.

Answer (score 0):

I am just guessing because I have not tested it, but maybe the bar can be the background color or right border, so you can do this to verify.

```
<a href="www.link.com">
    <img src="/images/image.png" style="max-height: 235px; 
                                    max-width: 100%;
                                    height: auto;
                                    width: auto; /* ie8 */
                                    background-color: none;
                                    border: none;" />
</a>
```